# Importing data from text file and creating graphs from it

Tags: excel, graph

I have a text file that carries date, time and 2 other types of numerical data. They are all seperated by a comma:

```
16.06.2021,18:57:15,584,26
16.06.2021,18:57:18,723,26
16.06.2021,18:57:21,724,26
16.06.2021,18:57:24,723,26
16.06.2021,18:57:27,723,26
16.06.2021,18:57:30,583,26
16.06.2021,18:57:33,724,26
16.06.2021,18:57:36,583,26
16.06.2021,18:57:39,723,26
16.06.2021,18:57:42,723,26
16.06.2021,18:57:45,723,26
16.06.2021,18:57:48,314,26
16.06.2021,18:57:51,733,26
16.06.2021,18:57:54,434,26
16.06.2021,18:57:57,514,26
16.06.2021,18:58:00,298,26
16.06.2021,18:58:03,299,26
16.06.2021,18:58:06,409,26
16.06.2021,18:58:09,679,26
16.06.2021,18:58:12,734,26
16.06.2021,18:58:15,734,26
16.06.2021,18:58:18,733,26
16.06.2021,18:58:21,733,26
16.06.2021,18:58:24,733,26
16.06.2021,18:58:27,733,26
16.06.2021,18:58:30,732,26
16.06.2021,18:58:33,733,26
```

I can successfully insert them into my Excel spreadsheet:

[image]

But creating a graph never works. For instance I want to feed the graph with time and and third numerical data to create a line graph but I end up with this:

[image]

Comment: The cells are text. You can probably select the column and use text to columns under data to make it numerical

Comment: That did it, thank you.